# Can't find data from database after set it?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js

I have a piece of code which adds data to the database, then a function which gets the added data ID from the database. Problem is that, I get an error it couldn't be found, but it is in the database. How could I solve the problem?

> [2017-06-03 18:01:25.855] [DEBUG] [default] - TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'id' of undefined

Here is how the function looks like

```
function getLastUser(hash, socket, user){
    query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE hash='+pool.escape(hash)+'', function(err, row){
        if(err){
            logger.error('Failed getting user hash: ' + user.name);
            logger.debug(err);
            socket.emit('message', {
                type: 'error',
                error: "Failed getting user hash"
            });
            return;
        }
        return row[0].id;
    });
}
```

Here the calling

```
getLastUser(hash, user, socket);
```

Comment: That means row[0] is undefined. Have you tried console.log on row and see what you get?

Comment: Do you get result when you run the same query in sql management studio?

Comment: **after set** - Query is async operation. Probably database can not set your user with hash in time. And while operation executing you try to get it. Can your show all code?

Comment: By using console.log I get all the results what I have requested.